# what means "評価欲しさに来る?

Tags: meaning

This is a line of dialogue Shingeki no kyojin S2 05:

> 自分の体調も把握できねぇやつが、 評価欲しさに来ちゃいけねぇ訓練を受けちまった。

what means "評価欲しさに来る? In general, when 評価欲しさ is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 評価欲しさに来ちゃいけねぇ訓練を受けちまった。
>   what means "**評価欲しさに来る**?

You're not parsing it correctly, I'm afraid. 評価欲しさに modifies 受けちまった, not 来ちゃいけねぇ. So the phrase you should be looking at is 評価欲しさに訓練を受けた, "received a training only for evaluation".

> 評価欲しさに（≂ 評価が欲しくて/評価されたくて）、｛（来ちゃいけねぇ）訓練を｝受けちまった。

So the whole sentence means "Someone who can't even assess/control his own physical condition ended up receiving a training {which he shouldn't have participated in}, only from a desire to get (favorably) evaluated / just for evaluation (or a grade/approval/admiration)." As you can see, the reason for 来ちゃいけねぇ (he shouldn't have come) is 自分の体調も把握できねぇ (he is incapable of assessing/controlling his own physical condition).

---

「XX + 欲しさに」 means "(only) for XX", "(only) from a desire to get/obtain XX." Examples:

> - 名声**欲しさに**してはいけないことをしてしまった。 I did something I shouldn't have done, *(only) from a desire to gain* fame / a reputation.
> - [金]{かね}**欲しさに**好きでもない男と結婚する marry a man I don't like *just for* money
> - 主役の座**欲しさに**監督に[媚]{こ}びを売る butter up the director *to get* the major role (in a drama or movie)

Answer (score 3):

> 評価｛ひょうか｝欲｛ほ｝しさに来｛く｝る

In other Japanese it could roughly be said like:

- 評価｛ひょうか｝が欲｛ほ｝しいので来｛く｝る  *He has come here because he wants to be evaluated.*
- 認めて欲しいので来｛く｝る  *He has come here because he wants to be recognized.*
- ほめて欲しいので来｛く｝る  *He has come here because he wants to be praised.*

評価 means evaluation.
For the person speaking this phrase might think that evaluation should be done only by a certain third party, not by the proposal of himself/herself for the evaluation. 
So, the speaker makes fun of him/her or makes a fool of him/her, because of his/her ignorance or rudeness by this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Without the context I'm not sure but it sounds like the speaker is speaking of someone who came to the training because "s/he wants a formal record that s/he completed the training."